# laptop not receiving proper power

Tags: laptop, keyboard, battery, charger

I have a laptop, ASUS x550j

- i7 4710HQ
- 8GB RAM
- Windows 10

From past few days i am having a problem, while i connect an external keyboard it doesn't work well. Sometimes it automatically presses a button and the delay speed etc. I have tried it with different keyboards and the result is same,
also the LED light on keyboard also doesn't work while connected to the laptop.

Also while I play high end games and my charger is connected, sometimes it goes to battery mode automatically and then I have to limit my frames or lower the graphics. Hn high graphics the laptop runs on battery even if the charger is connected.

What could be the possible reason for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You list multiple problems with the same laptop possibly linked to the charger. Here's what I would do:

1. Get a different charger (with more power). Could be a generic one or an original.
2. If that does not help: reinstall Windows.

If neither helps, your laptop is damaged and needs to be replaced under warranty. If the warranty has expired, get a new laptop.